# Как сделать предзагрузку контента в блоке div с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть блок `<div id="contents">` в котором есть много контента, из за него сайт долго грузится, как спомощью `js` отключитьзагрузку в этом блоке до полной загрузки сайта и показать текст `Идет загрузка...` А уже когда загрузится весь контент в этом блоке, показать его.

Comment: в `<div id="contents">` грузится определенное число записей?

Comment: там с базы тексты с картинками грузятся

Comment: Тем не менее ответ на мой вопрос я не получил.

Comment: Если контент блока - обычная разметка, ответ - никак.

Здесь необходимо комплексное решение: сервер отдает в одном запросе страницу с пустым блоком, в другом - содержимое этого блока. Тогда javascript сможет подгрузить данные отдельно - вторым запросом.

Comment: А если помистить этот блок в отдельный php файл, и так после повной загрузки сайта подгрузить его с помощью js